# Mulitple Login Pages using ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to create two ASP.NET Membership login pages for an ASP.NET website I'm creating.

Here is structure:

```
/ - Anonymous Access for page off root

/registeredUser - Must be part of RegisteredUser Role
/registeredUser/login.aspx - Login page Registered Users  

/admin - Must be part of AdminUser Role
/admin/login.aspx - Login page Admin Users
```

Another person asked the question and it was suggested to use the location tag in the web.confg:
[Redirect user to Mulitple Login Pages using ASP.NET Membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525988/redirect-user-to-mulitple-login-pages-using-asp-net-membership)

But I receive errors related to the using the forward slash / in the location path. I removed the forward slashes and the security rules are ignored.

So my question is, can I have more than one logon page using ASP.NET Membership without creating separate applications in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to redirect the user to other login page from the default login page in the Page Load event:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim returnURL As String = Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl")

  If returnURL <> String.Empty AndAlso returnURL.Contains("registeredUser") Then
     Response.Redirect("~/registeredUser/login.aspx?" & AntiXss.UrlEncode(returnURL))
  End If
End Sub
```

This is based on an suggestion from David Qain at: http://forums.asp.net/t/1348477.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use one login page and call [***ascx***](http://www.codersource.net/asp_net_web_user_controls.html) Controls

This will require single url and custom display will be easy on aspx Login Page

Comment: The requirement is two login pages. This would allow a redirect to a login page per section, opposed to a share one.